# Certain fields (spanning across object relationship) displayed as blank in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter, custom, wire

We have a custom object called a "Plan" (API NAME: `Plan__c`).
Plans have rather complex relationships with contacts. In order to account for the complexity of the relationships, we have a custom object called Plan Contacts (API Name: `PCR__c`) <-- "plan contact relationships). PCRs have a master-detail field/relationship to both a plan and contact (`Plan__c/__r` and `Contact__c/__r`, respectively)

I am building a lightning web component (`planContactContainer`) to display the complex relationships in more digestable way.
The first thing I am attempting to do is to display a list of PCRs in a lightning-datatable component.
While it seems like I have hooked up everything properly, None of the fields that I am importing from the Contact object are coming over.
Here is my .html for the `planContactContainer`

```
<template>
<h1>Plan Contacts</h1>
<lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
    <lightning-tab label='All'>
        <lightning-card>
            
        </lightning-card>
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Owners">
        <lightning-card>
            
        </lightning-card>
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Officers">
        <lightning-card>
            
        </lightning-card>
    </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Trustees">
            <template if:true={trustees.data}>
                <lightning-card>
                    <lightning-datatable
                        key-field="Id"
                        data={trustees.data}
                        columns={trusteeColumns}
                    ></lightning-datatable>        
                </lightning-card>
            </template>
            <template if:false={trustees.data}>
                <lightning-card>
                    <lightning-card>
                        <p>There are no Trustees</p>
                    </lightning-card>       
                </lightning-card>
            </template>
            <template if:true={trustees.errors}>
                <p>{trustees.errors}</p>
            </template>
        </lightning-tab>        
</lightning-tabset>
```

And here is the .js file

```
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import getTrustees from '@salesforce/apex/PlanContactController.getTrustees';
import PCR__C_TRUSTEE__C_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/PCR__c.Trustee__c';
import PCR__C_CONTACT__R_FIRST_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/PCR__c.Contact__r.firstName';
import PCR__C_CONTACT__R_LAST_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/PCR__c.Contact__r.lastName';
import PCR__C_CONTACT__R_EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/PCR__c.Contact__r.Email';
import PCR__C_CONTACT__R_PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/PCR__c.Contact__r.Phone';

const TRUSTEE_COLUMNS =
    [
        {
            label: 'First Name',
            fieldName: PCR__C_CONTACT__R_FIRST_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName,
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            label: 'Last Name',
            fieldName: PCR__C_CONTACT__R_LAST_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName,
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            label: 'Email',
            fieldName: PCR__C_CONTACT__R_EMAIL_FIELD.fieldApiName,
            type: 'email'
        },
        {
            label: 'Phone',
            fieldName: PCR__C_CONTACT__R_PHONE_FIELD.fieldApiName,
            type: 'phone'
        },
        {
            label: 'Is Trustee?',
            fieldName: PCR__C_TRUSTEE__C_FIELD.fieldApiName,
            type: 'boolean',           
        }
        
    ];


export default class PlanContactContainer extends LightningElement {

    trusteeColumns = TRUSTEE_COLUMNS

    @wire(getTrustees)
    trustees;


}
```

And here is the apex controller class

```
public class PlanContactController {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<PCR__c> getTrustees() {
        List<PCR__c> pcrs = [SELECT ID, Trustee__c, Plan__c, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name,Contact__r.firstName,Contact__r.lastName,Contact__r.Email,Contact__r.Phone FROM PCR__c];
        
        return pcrs;
    }
}
```

The JS-meta file allows for the component to go on a Plan__c record page, but I will not include here as I don't think it is necessary. (But will do so if someone determines it to be necessary)

When the component is displayed on a plans's record page, all of the fields that are native to the contact (fName, lName, etc) are displaying as blank. However the fields native the the PCR itself are displaying properly (eg. `is Trustee` field)
[image: Screenshot of lwc on Plan__c object lightning page. All fields are blank in all columns except for the checkbox field (which happens to be the only imported field that is not spanning across another relationship)]

I don't know if I am importing something incorrectly, or I am missing some fundamental limitation of LWC, or what the issue might be.

A couple things to note:
-I am aware that the "getTrustees" method in the controller is returning *EVERY* PCR, this code is a work-in-progress.
-I am relatively new to LWC, so I am probably missing somehting fundamental

Thanks in advance